# Insert random blocks in a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have posts that I am displaying through a `foreach` loop. Within this I would like to throw in some advertising blocks.

I have posts and advertising blocks working with no issues. The posts are coming from an array and the advertising blocks I am manually inserted.

The hiccup I am seeing is how I am throwing in these ads into the `foreach` loop. I want it to add them but not interrupt the posts themselves and that is what I am experiencing.

I have 3 advertising blocks and 12 posts per page. When the page loads there should be a total of 15 blocks and instead I am getting 9. Those ads also not static - I have them coming in to be placed anywhere within those 15 blocks in total.

Here is quick run down of the script I am using (a readers digest version).

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($posts AS $post) { 
   $i++; 
   if ($adblock == $i) {
        //insert advertisement block
   }
   else if ($adblock == $i) {
        //insert advertisement block
   }
   else if ($adblock == $i) {
        //insert advertisement block
   }
   else {
        //insert post block
   } 
}
```

Comment: Use modulus. `if (($i % 3) == 0) { //insert ad }`

Comment: That is perfect and will give it a go!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without too much complexity, if the number of posts/adv per page is static, you can use a simple math to place your adv like this:

```
$i=0;
foreach($posts as $post){
  $i++; 

  if($i%3==0) { /* insert additional adv block */ }

  /* insert post block at anytime*/
}
```

you can change the ($i%3==0) to any other number; with 3 you will get an adv every 3 posts. need more adv, make it ($i%2==0), need less, make it ($i%4==0), etc.

Comment: Shouldn't be an `if/else` - it should ONLY be IF to insert the adv FOLLOWED by the next post and NOT an ELSE, which will skip the post itself. But beside that the idea is okay.: `if($i%3==0) { /* insert adv block */ } /*insert post block*/`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input; there shouldn't have been an else in there. Comes in perfect and random!!